# Checkin updated assembly version information if only if build is successful

Tags: teamcity, assemblyinfo

In my build workflow I change the assembly version information in AssemblyInfo.cs. How can I check-in my changes at the end of the build process only if build was successful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create new build configuration in the TeamCity Project.
2. In the new build configuration go to Build Steps and add Build Feature and select AssemblyInfo Patcher.

   > AssemblyInfo Patcher build feature allows to set a build number to an assembly 
   >   automatically, without having to patch AssemblyInfo.cs files manually. When adding this 
   >   build feature you need only to specify version format.
3. Add another Build Step that will commits pending changes in the current workspace -  [Checkin Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
4. In your Main Project go to "Build Triggers"

> "Build triggers are used to add builds to the queue either when an
>   event occurs (like a VCS check-in) or periodically with some
>   configurable interval."

In Build Triggering add new trigger - "Finish Build Trigger"

> Finished Build Trigger will add a build to the queue after a build finishes in the selected configuration.

In Build configuration select the build Project created previously (Step 1) and **don't forget to select the check box Trigger after successful build only.**